# How can I replace content in a PDF file using PHP?

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I have one issue about PDF file.

I generate dynamic PDF template (Like Certificate). The file content some fields like Firstname, Lastname, Course type, etc.

I want to write dynamic content into PDF as firstname, lastname etc.

I have tried MPDF, FPDF etc tools, but they are not working. I also used PDF to HTML conversation but after converting HTML regenerates not possible from html into proper format.

Please let me know if anyone have other idea to direct replace content into Existing pdf using PHP.

I have sample pdf files.

I want to replace content into given attachment. [This](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2017/07_w29/1182718/Certi-FWT-basis-en-opfris_PDF.pdf) is a demo file I have many files with different templates.

Comment: You say that you have tried different libraries, and claim that they are "not working". Not working how? What did you try? What was the expected output and what was the actual output? You need to show us your attempts since SO is for when you're having issues with your _existing_ code.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Comment: @peterh Thank you for transferring me knowledge about English. But that wasn't my question if you can read easily. Your eyes can't read ahead of I??

Comment: @Gopu Yes - this is why I didn't write an answer, but a comment (and I corrected your question, too). As I've got similar advices as beginner (and better English speakers corrected my posts, too), I was happy on that.

Comment: @peterh Sorry, my previous comment wasn't offensive. I appreciate you helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, get away from your thoughts one could easiely change anything in a pdf from PHP.

The one way to do such thing like generating a certificate for anyone is to generate a "blank" pdf and then put in the names with names with a php libarary (like Zend_Pdf or anything else).

To make it short: There is no (easy, free) way to manipulate data in a PDF.
To make it complicated: Yes, there is a way. One have to open the file, read it's content, understand where to search for the variables, manipulate the data and regenerate the pdf with a pdf generator. And yes, i know, it is very complicated, so stay at the short and easy way: Generate a blanko and put in the variables as needed ;)